# Initialize a dynamic vector without knowing the final lenght

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i'm trying to do a (probably) simple thing. But i have some dubts. I want to initialize an array in C. But i don't know how many elements i will need at the end of the loop. So i was thinking to allocate it dynamically, in this way:

```
int *segment;
int index=0;

for (i=0; i<height; i++) 
{
    for (j=0; j<width; j++) 
    {
         if ("some_condition_is_verified"){

             segment[index] = (int)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
             segment[index] = 5;  // 5 is only for example.
             index++;     
         }    
    }   
}
```

I believe that this declaration it is not good, because it gives me this error: 
 `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]`
, o in which way i could do? Is this wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What is your intention for `segment`? How and when do you want it to grow?

Comment: in this double `for` i check a condition. Everytime that this condition is verified i have to create a new empty slot of memory of `segment` and initialize it with a value of interest. I hope the is clear what i mean.

Comment: It would appear you desire a geometric `realloc()` loop that final-sizes once it finishes (not that it would matter, but it would be good form none-the-less). honestly I would initial-size to `width*height`, fill what you can, and when finished `realloc()` down to the size you actually used.

Comment: I waited this time to answer to test this funcion "realloc()" on my code. And it works nicely. So thanks for the answer, it was useful

Answer (score 1):

*Is this wrong?*

`segment[index]` type is `int`

fix code sample like this:

```
int *segment;
int index=0;

segment = calloc(height*width, sizeof(int));//ensure a maximum memory for vector.
for (i=0; i<height; i++){
    for (j=0; j<width; j++){
         if ("some_condition_is_verified"){
             segment[index++] = 5;  // 5 is only for example.
         }    
    }   
}
segment = realloc(segment, index*sizeof(int));//reduce the size,
```

Comment: If there are reasonable upper bounds to `width` and `height` is it really necessary to `realloc`? More trouble than it is worth unless you are really that low on memory/disk space

Comment: @EdHeal I think the upper limit is determined from the height and width of this code. I think I like better realloc every time.

Comment: You have already allocated enough memory so the issue is why the need to reclaim memory? If you have reasonable values for height/width then perhaps a few MBs will not go amiss and is the reallocation worthwhile?

Comment: @EdHeal It is by way of thinking. 
Probably  not that bad with realloc in the same way.
It may be that he does not want to to secure the extra From a policy the original code.

Comment: @EdHeal Please illustrates an easy-to-understand it if there is a serious drawback something.

Comment: Waste of CPU effort for little gain (if any). Also memory fragmentation if the same thing needs to be carried out after the memory is reclaimed with a different condition

Comment: @EdHeal I do not think division of memory is so much to occur When compared to doing realloc every time. 
  It does not cause disruption of memory (and _little gain_ for CPU, How much'm critical!) , such as is said to reduce the memory by realloc perhaps.

Comment: It does not make a big deal of CPU cost of a single reallloc of memory reduction.

Answer (score 0):

`calloc` does not return an `int`, but a pointer to an `int` (an `int *`).

The correct code would be

```
 segment = (int *) calloc(1, sizeof(int));
```

from there, you can use the pointer as an array (essentially, arrays are just statically allocated "pointers").

Comment: `calloc()` returns `void *`, not an `int *`. And the correct code would be `segment = calloc(1, sizeof(*segment))` (*without* the cast).

Comment: after that i have to give to segment[x] a value. Something like:
    `segment[x]=2;`
this allocation is ok for that?
And why you don't use an index? Isn't necessary?